# C# Find specific text in listbox

Tags: c#, string, text, listbox

I'm creating an application that runs a Java server in the background and outputs to a console listbox with each new line. However, I want to be able to create a timer for example that constantly reads the console listbox for certain pre-determined things but not specific.

For example, if the server outputs "[17:32:50 INFO]: Matt[127.0.0.1]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)" and adds it to the console listbox as an item, I want to be able to just grab the "Matt" part and add it to a list of players currently online in a players listbox. The "entity ID" and "co-ordinates in world" will be different every time so cannot be determined.

As well as this I'd like to do the same thing when the player disconnects, the console listbox will add an item that will say "Matt left the game" and I'd need it to be able to search the players listbox for "Matt" and remove that item.

I'm wondering if this is possible, apologies if this isn't very clear!

Comment: Can you give us the example of what you tried? It's easier to edit your failed attempt than guessing what you have on your mind.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I have no clue how I could possible do it. The only way I can think of is possibly getting all the text before the "[" character. Apologies for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you want to get the players name and then either add or remove it from an "Online Players" listbox, you can use `Substring()` to search inside a string starting at x index and selecting for y length.

Here's an updated version for you that should work with the new format:

```
private void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add example logins
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[17:32:50 INFO]: Amy[/127.0.0.1:12345]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[18:42:51 INFO]: Dan[/255.255.255.255:23451]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[19:33:27 INFO]: Matt[/1.1.1.1:34512]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[02:17:03 INFO]: Some Really Long Screen Name[/292.192.92.2:45123]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[09:05:55 INFO]: ABC $!@#$ 12341234[/127.0.0.1:51234]logged in with entity ID 233 at ([world]co-ordinates in world)");

    AnalyzeConsoleOutput(lstConsoleOutput, lstOnlinePlayers);
}

private void cmdLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add example logouts
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[22:12:12 INFO]: Amy left the game");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[23:44:15 INFO]: Matt left the game");
    lstConsoleOutput.Items.Add("[24:00:00 INFO]: ABC $!@#$ 12341234 left the game");

    AnalyzeConsoleOutput(lstConsoleOutput, lstOnlinePlayers);
}

private void AnalyzeConsoleOutput(ListBox listboxToAnalyze, ListBox onlinePlayersListbox)
{
    const string LoginIdentifier = "]logged in with entity";
    const string LogoutIdentifer = " left the game";
    string playerName;

    foreach (var item in listboxToAnalyze.Items)
    {
        // Check if a player has logged in and add them to the players list box
        if (item.ToString().Contains(LoginIdentifier))
        {
            int startOfPlayerNameIndex = item.ToString().IndexOf("]: ") + 3;
            int lengthOfPlayerName = item.ToString().IndexOf('[', item.ToString().IndexOf('[') + 1) - startOfPlayerNameIndex;

            playerName = item.ToString().Substring(startOfPlayerNameIndex, lengthOfPlayerName);

            if (!onlinePlayersListbox.Items.Contains(playerName))
            {
                onlinePlayersListbox.Items.Add(playerName);
            }
        }

        // Check if a player has logged out and remove them from the players list box
        if (item.ToString().Contains(LogoutIdentifer))
        {
            int startOfPlayerNameIndex = item.ToString().IndexOf("]: ") + 3;
            int lengthOfPlayerName = item.ToString().IndexOf(LogoutIdentifer, 0) - startOfPlayerNameIndex;

            playerName = item.ToString().Substring(startOfPlayerNameIndex, lengthOfPlayerName);

            if (onlinePlayersListbox.Items.Contains(playerName))
            {
                onlinePlayersListbox.Items.Remove(playerName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This now uses 2 variables to set the start index of the players name and another to set the number of characters to count.  By doing it this way, if the format changes in the future you only need to update these things and everything else should still work.  I've also kept the 2 consts for LoginIdentifier and LogoutIdentifier that you can change if needed.

This should also work with or without a / in the IP address.  So either "[111" or "[/111" should still work fine with this.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly, however there's an issue on my part. I've just noticed when someone logs in, it actually looks like this: "[17:32:04 INFO]: Matt[/127.0.0.1:25565]logged in with entity id 177 at ([world](their coordinatesinworld)" I apologise for this I should've seen it sooner, is there anyway I can just simply change the LoginIdentifier? As the problem is the "entity id" and coordinatesinworld will always be different. Again, thanks a lot and apologies for the confusion on my part.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the start of the string.  I'll look at that now.  Just wondering, do you need to know what the "entity id" or "coordinatesinworld" are?  Because if not you can just change LoginIdentifier to something like "]logged in with entity id".

Comment: They're not important I just thought maybe it would make the code harder to do because the players name is in between two things that can't really be determined. Also, thanks a lot dude.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  However you can update the code to search on the parts that you know will always be the same like "]logged in with entity id" or "INFO]: ".  I updated my answer for you with some new code that should work with this format.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Also my apologies but I just realized your comments have it written like Matt[/127 but your edited question has it written as Matt[127.  Could you please clarify which format it is?  My updated code works on [/127 and won't work if it's just [127.

Comment: Hey, just noticed sorry, yeah the IP has a / in it so like Ellis[/127.0.0.1] but the IP will always be different for different people. However the code seems to work fine! The only issue I'm having is getting it to remove the users name once they've left.

Comment: Oh that's okay. I think I know what the problem with the remove is now.  Do all the "name has left the game" have something in front of them as well like [xx:xx:xx INFO]: Matt has left the game?

Comment: Yeah, very sorry I should've mentioned, everything that feeds back from the server has the [xx:xx:xx INFO]: before it such as. Again, apologies I should've mentioned this earlier. Appreciate the help massively!

Comment: No problem and you're welcome.  I've just updated my answer again with an updated example that should work with your new format for both adding and removing players.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks a lot for all the help you've saved me a monster headache!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
{
    // use the currently iterated list box item

    if (listBoxItem.ToString().Contains("logged"))
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, this works great for finding the correct item! However, doesn't help me collect certain text from that item, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the listbox's items and search for objects that are split and pick the "left" side of the split.

```
string CheckForMatchNames()
{
    foreach(string item in listbox.items)
        for (int i = 0; i < preDeterminedStringArrayThatMustMatchSomething.Length; i++)
            if (item.Split('[')[0] == preDeterminedStringArrayThatMatchesSomething[i])
                return preDeterminedStringArrayThatMustMatchSomething[i];
    return "none";
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm struggling to get this code to work without errors however I've put in the information it would need and still errors. Also, I'm not sure this would just get the "Matt" part of the string would it?

Comment: It would for the logging in, not for the logging out, but you've already got your answer. I tried.